# How to load Adam values from TensorFlow checkpoint in PyTorch? What is the structure of PyTorch's optimizer state_dict?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I need to port a model from **TF1** to **PyTorch**. I have pretty much everything figured out, except how to transfer the Adam values.

To be precise, each weight in the TF checkpoint has an associated `Adam` and `Adam_1` value which I would assume to be the `exp_avg` and `exp_avg_sq` in the PyTorch optimizer `state_dict`.

The problem is that the PyTorch optimizer `state_dict` does not have a structure I understand. We have:

```py
state_dict["optimizer"]["state"][0]["exp_avg"].shape = torch.Size([150697984])
```

and

```py
state_dict["optimizer"]["state"][1]["exp_avg"].shape = torch.Size([25327])
```

for a total of `150 723 311` values. However if I count the number of elements in `state_dict["model"]` I get `159 319 780` and even if I ignore BatchNorm parameters, it is still `159 213 487`, so about 9 million more than in the optimizer values.

There is also the small snag that the optimizer values are stored in one long list (1D Tensor) and I don't know how to map position in that list to parameter in the model which I would need to map it to the TF checkpoint, since that stores the Adam values nested beside the weights.

(Same problem with the optimizer values being split into two chunks like that.)

I was unable to find information on this mapping and am also confused as to the numbers mismatch.